# How to trim <text> from MVC cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, model-view-controller

Using MVC, I have the following if statement in the javascript portion of my CSHTML:

```
var url = '@if (@HttpContext.Current.Session["id"].ToString() == "1")
{
    <text>Testing one two three</text>
}
else
{
    @Url.Action("GetCustomer", "Customer")

}';
```

If I go into the **ELSE** portion, everything is fine and the following is produced:

```
var url = '/Customer/GetCustomer';
```

However, if I go into the **IF** portion, I am getting too much white space:

```
var url = '                  
Testing one two three  ';
```

My question is, how can I trim that extra white space out and show as follows:

```
var url = 'Testing one two three';
```

Thank You before hand.

Thanks to **Ciubotariu Florin** here is the answer:

```
var url = '@(HttpContext.Current.Session["id"].ToString() == "1" ? "Testing one two three" : @Url.Action("GetCustomer", "Customer") )';
```

Comment: do you want to show <text>@url</text> ?

Comment: Hi Hien, I would like to show 'Testing one two three' with no white space for the IF portion.  Thank you.

Comment: why the text in razor without space and display having space?

Comment: Can you explain the circumstance for having <text> block in the if statement? Where is it from? How is it generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `<text></text>` tags:

```
var url = '@(HttpContext.Current.Session["id"].ToString() == "1" ? "Testing one two three" : @Url.Action("GetCustomer", "Customer") )';
```

Comment: Ciubotariu, thank you, I think you are real close!  But it is displaying this:  var url = 1 == "1" ?
                 "Testing one two three" :
                  /Customer/GetCustomer
Instead of this: var url = 'Testing one two three';

Comment: Thank you Ciubotariu Florin, you led me to the answer!  Here it is: var url = '@(HttpContext.Current.Session["id"].ToString() == "1" ? "Testing one two three" : @Url.Action("GetCustomer", "Customer") )';

Comment: Just wanted to do that :) I'll edit my answer. Can you mark my answer as correct if it helped you?